# regex to match non-latin char with ASCII 0-31 and 128-255

Tags: java, regex, non-latin

wanted to match the non-latin char. tried it. as per my understanding   `if (a.matches("[\\x8A-\\xFF]+"))` should return true but its false.

```
String a = "Ž";
if (a.matches("[\\x8A-\\xFF]+"))
{

}
```

Comment: "Ž" is not in that range.

Comment: "Ž" is 8E which is in the range

Comment: You mean you want to disregard from the diacritics?

Comment: False.  In Unicode, "Ž" is 0x017D - http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf

Comment: What is your intent? To match all the characters in your range and also `Ž`? Then just add it to the character class `"[\\x8A-\\xFF\\u017D]+"`. If you want to find the extended characters only, you have an answer already.

Comment: @Romi *"Ž is 8E"*--in extended latin charset, not Unicode.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: probably you're misunderstanding the codepoint of the character in some codepage/charset with Unicode. Read this [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I meant a reference for the extended latin charset that says Ž is 8E.

Comment: @aioobe you're right, not 8E, but AE in ISO Latin-2 charset: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/goglobal/cc305168.aspx. But it still "fits" the range provided in OP's example.

Comment: @aioobe I won't surprise if there is some Czech or Polish custom charset where Ž is exactly 8E (for example, for Cyrillic we have 5 or more different charsets)

Comment: Yes. This was what I was curious about. If it was clear where Ž = 8E came from, it would be easier to sort out where the confusion came from and to provide a good answer.

Comment: @aioobe look: https://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/1250.gif. It is Windows-1250 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)

Comment: http://www.ascii-code.com/ here in found Ž = 8E

Comment: @Romi When you have String in Java, you are working with Unicode character (well, you still need to be aware that String in Java is UTF-16). Pattern in Java, since Java 5, always matches in term of Unicode code point. How the character is encoded in some other encoding is irrelevant when you hold a String. It has been take care of when you decode the byte stream into String.

Answer (score 6):

Judging from your title:

> Regex to match non-latin char with ASCII 0-31 and 128-255

it seems you're after all characters except those in range 32-127 and you're surprised Ž doesn't match.

If this is correct, I suggest you use the expression `[^\x20-\x7F]` (*"all characters except those in range 32-127"*). This *does* match Ž.

(An exact translation of the regex in your title would look like `[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]` but this still doesn't match Ž as described below.)

**Why your initial attempt didn't work:**

The `\xNN` matches characters *unicode values*. The unicode value for Ž is 0x017D, i.e. it falls outside of the range `\x8A`-`\xFF`.

When you say *"Ž" is 8E* you're most likely seeing a value from an extended ASCII table, and these are not the values that the Java regex engine works with.

Comment: if (a.matches("[\\x8A-\\xFF]+")) its not matching its returning false.

Comment: @Romi Exactly, you should negate the character group.

Comment: @aioobe than what will be the regexp expression to match 0-31 and 128-159. as i want to include extended char like "Ž" too.

Comment: That would be `[\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]`, but as I mention in my answer, regular expressions doesn't work with ascii-values. So it's not clear that that expression will work for you.

Comment: @Romi, if you tell me exactly what characters you want to match (and I mean characters, not ASCII-values) then I can help you put together a regular expression. (If you just provide extended ASCII values I don't know which code page you're talking about (8E can in fact mean different things depending on which code page you're using) and regular expressions don't work together with ASCII values outside the range 0-127.)

Comment: @aiboobe : on given page I see that Ž is 8E still does not match to given regular expression.

Comment: Ah, right. But check [this page](http://www.ascii-codes.com/) (it lists Ä for 8E), or [this page](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-mac.htm) (it lists é for 8E). So which one should we look at when we write regexps? Well, none of those, because those are ASCII tables. We should look at a table showing unicode codepoints, such as [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). As you can see on that page, Ž is in fact 0x017D.

Comment: Now, here's a potential follow-up question: *But if I write the byte 0x8E in a file on my system, it will be printed as Ž!* It may be the case that your default encoding indeed maps 0x8E to Ž. However, when Java reads 0x8E and translates it to Ž, it will forget that it once was 0x8E on disk and it will *just* remember the symbol Ž. So when you try to match it, 0x8E isn't around anymore. Ž is around, and when encountering a `\xNN` expression, it will look at the unicode codepoint for Ž which is 0x017D.

Comment: @Romi, is my answer (and comments) clear? Anything still unresolved?